# How to set more than 1 index on typeorm class

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, typescript-decorator

I have this:

```
@t.Unique("user-hash-device", ["userId", "hash", "deviceId"])
@t.Index({expireAfterSeconds: 1814400})  // <<< this line causes bug
@t.Entity('vibe_trace')
export class Trace extends From<Trace> { 
// ...
}
```

the line above causes this bug:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/10781

so my question is - how can I set multiple indexes safely on a typeorm collection/table? I want to set a (1) unique index and then (2) expire documents (using TTL index)